# How can I protect a vending machine wire from being cut again?

Tags: electrical, wire, protection

A friend of mine operates a vending machine in a school. Oftentimes, there are issues when a snack gets stuck in the machine, the students will rock the machine. Rocking the machine is an issue, because when the (very heavy) machine comes down on the wire, the wire can get cut. My friend has gotten people to patch it up a few times, most recently myself (simple job -- snip, strip, twist, and tape everything together).
However, the current situation is definitely not optimal -- I don't think we have a lot of wire to use :P

Therefore, I ask -- **how can I protect the wire to prevent this from occurring again?**

Comment: Bolt the machine down?  Tape the wire so it's not hanging on the floor?

Comment: How is it that the cords are arranged so that this is even possible?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because very few houses have vending machines in them.

Comment: @NiallC. I didn't realize that that would be the case; my impression of the site was that all DIY (as the URL implies) would be on-topic. Thank you for explaining the close reason. [ *As an aside, I do know at least one person who has a functional vending machine in their basement -- but you're right, very few* :) ]

Comment: @Mazura They're lying on the floor, after coming out of the machine. The cords curve around the back of the machine to make their way to the outlet (which is on the other side of the machine from where they're attached).

Comment: People with man-caves and rowdy, drunk friends may need this someday.

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to probably have a warning on the machines, in a very visible manner, informing them to NOT shake the machine.

Comment: @cVplZ That's been tried in the past, but without much success. People either don't pay attention or don't believe that their actions really damage the machine.

Comment: `(simple job -- snip, strip, twist, and tape everything together).` **Do not do this with flexible cable, or anything at mains voltage**. Taping and twisting does not ensure a secure connection, especially when the cable is pulled. Tape is not a rugged method of insulation. NZ rules forbid joins of any sort in flexible cable; I would assume the US is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if the cord is protected by FMC (flexible metal conduit), once the unit falls on it, it'd best be inspected anyway.

Install an **Anti-tip Bracket** on top of the unit: ([intelligentvending.co.uk](http://www.intelligentvending.co.uk/security-equipment/vending-machine-anti-tilt-wall-brackets.htm))

[image]

If the owner of the building will not let you secure a vending machine to the wall (which *has* fallen over multiple times) it's time to find a new place to put it; neither of you should want the liability of not having an anti-tip. And then never set foot in the building again; who knows what else is going on in there...

-Note, use a purchased replacement cord, wired inside the machine (no splicing outside the unit) and cord strain reliefs (grommets).

---

Also, you need the sticker where the machine [eats you](http://clov.com/blog/2012/02/the-warning-signs/) if you shake it.

[image]

Comment: The cord is not protected by FMC -- I might suggest that to my friend. Thanks for the answer!